# Complement of a verb

Tags: gerunds

I am not sure whether my question is correct or incorrect but a question arose in my mind about VERB COMPLEMENT when reading the book namely (Wren & Martin).

The sentence was:

Seeing is believing.

In the given sentence, whether 'believing' is VERB COMPLEMENT or SUBJECT COMPLEMENT?

As I have done my research on this sentence on Google and studied about complement and its types as well as uses.  So I am really confused to distinguish between Subject complement and verb complement in the given example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there anyone WHO could explain this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Seeing is believing.

This is an example of **subject complement**. The statement asserts that to see some thing implies that one will believe in the existence of that thing. "Believing" redefines "seeing", making it a subject complement.

"Is" is this verb in this sentence. "Believing" would be a verb complement if we thought that it applied to "is". This would imply that "seeing" was somehow existing in a manner described as believing, which doesn't really make sense.